# What are the default values of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_event.conf?

Tags: apache2, php, configuration, default

I added a php code to my sites that created errors like this:

```
AH00484: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

and before I figured out what was actually going on, I went to change the values on `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_event.conf`.

Now my values are:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
        StartServers                     2
        MinSpareThreads          25
        MaxSpareThreads          75
        ThreadLimit                      64
        ThreadsPerChild          25
        MaxRequestWorkers         400
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

Now I understand and solved the problem, and I would like to restore the default values, just to not make other messes, but I have absolutely no idea what they were.

Can someone tell me the default values, please?

Comment: These are the default values:

`<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestWorkers     150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>`
@alebal

Comment: The above default values in the comment Apache 2.3 or older versions. I have updated the answer with apache 2.4. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied @alebal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this official [doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxconnectionsperchild),
these are the default values:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers             3
    MinSpareThreads          75
    MaxSpareThreads          250
    ThreadLimit              64
    ThreadsPerChild          25
    MaxRequestWorkers        400
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

The default values for `MaxRequestWorkers` are calculated like this:

```
MaxRequestWorkers 400 (16 x 25 = 400)
ServerLimit 16 (default)
ThreadsPerChild 25 (default)
```